# WlanEnumInterfaces don't return Guid C# Whit P/Invoke

Tags: pinvoke

Hy Guy i have a a problem whit c# to call a native function wlanenuminterfaces 
the function return ok = (0) but i don't know why... the Guid of interface is all {000000000000000000}
why? someone can help me ? thanks so much i pos the code...

```
[DllImport("wlanapi.dll")]
internal static extern int WlanEnumInterfaces([In]IntPtr HandleClient,   [In,Out]IntPtr Reserved,  [In,Out]  WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST ine);`

 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal class WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST
{
    internal int dwNumberOfItems;
    internal int dwIndex;
    internal  WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO[] InterfaceInfo;

}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal class WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO
{
    internal Guid interfaceGuid;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    internal string strInterfaceDescription;
    internal WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE Istate;
}


internal enum WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE
{
    wlan_interface_state_not_ready = 0,
    wlan_interface_state_connected = 1,
    wlan_interface_state_ad_hoc_network_formed = 2,
    wlan_interface_state_disconnecting = 3,
    wlan_interface_state_disconnected = 4,
    wlan_interface_state_associating = 5,
    wlan_interface_state_discovering = 6,
    wlan_interface_state_authenticating = 7
}
 info = new WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST();
        list = new WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO();


       IntPtr info1 =  Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(info));
       IntPtr list1 =  Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(list));



        int enuminterface = Win32Intereop.WlanEnumInterfaces(handle, IntPtr.Zero, info);
        if (enuminterface != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problema Enum Interface");
        }

        IntPtr num = (IntPtr)info.dwNumberOfItems;
        info.dwNumberOfItems = Marshal.ReadInt32(num);

        info.InterfaceInfo = new WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO[info.dwNumberOfItems];


        for (int i = 0; i < info.dwNumberOfItems; i++)
        {

            info.InterfaceInfo[i] = list;
        }
```

Comment: You can find all this stuff ready for use in Managed WiFi project: http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/ Just use it directly or copy PInvoke declarations you need from there.

Comment: thanks for your response i see the site you sent but i want understand why don't work guid :)

Comment: You are not properly initializing your WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST.  You must set the dwNumberOfItems and create the array before making the call.